# C# windows form progress bar with a function on background worker

Tags: c#, excel, progress-bar, add-in, backgroundworker

I am attempting to add a progress bar (MARQUEE style) in my c# excel add in.  The progress bar appears but it does not indicate any progress until the function is finished executing, meaning that it remains frozen.

These are the functions in the Windows Form Class:

```
    public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            //run in back thread
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i); 
        }
    }

    //call back method
    public void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    //call back method
    public void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) 
    {
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Maximum;
    }
```

This is how I call the function from the add in button:

```
    private void buttonClicked(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        AddInPlanView.Form1 pBar = new AddInPlanView.Form1();
        pBar.Visible = true;
        pBar.backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        pBar.backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(pBar.backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        pBar.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(pBar.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        pBar.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(pBar.backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        pBar.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

        FUNCTIONTORUN();

        pBar.Visible = false;
    }
```

My code now attempts to put the progress bar on a background worker. I know I should switch this so that `FUNCTIONTORUN()` should be on a background worker, but how do I go about doing that?  Since it is a marquee progress bar I do not need to update the value of the progress bar at all, it just needs to run until `FUNCTIONTORUN()` ends.  Note that `FUNCTIONTORUN()` updates the cells of an Excel worksheet.

The progress bar is initialized using the Visual Studio designer.  The name of the `ProgressBar` object in the form class is `progressbar1`.

Answer (score 1):

to start a marquee style progress bar, type

```
progressbar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;

progressbar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 100;
```

to stop the marquee type

```
progressbar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed= 0;
```

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9e51ad57-988e-4c17-98f0-cd2a8abec503/

Answer (score 1):

```
FUNCTIONTORUN(); // make your UI thread busy. 

System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); // might help in this case.
```

In most of this sort of cases DoEvent doesn't help (according to my experience). So, it's quite difficult to get process bar to work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

When the Background worker completes just stop the progress bar.

Inside of this function `pBar.backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` just call the Stop function for the progress bar.

Comment: While FUNCTIONTORUN() is executing though, the progress bar does not function properly

Comment: ah that is because the FUNCTIONTORUN() is blocking the thread. That function should be what's in the background thread.

Comment: Yeah, so how would I do that? I don't need FUNCTIONTORUN() to report any progress update to the progress bar since it is a marquee style.

Comment: @Sam: you don't need to notify about progress to ProgressBar from the function, but considering the fact that it's, I immagine, long running task, you provide progress information for "outside". In this specific case the "outside" is a progress bar too. So function reports progress, but ProgressBar listens for that. What is not ok here?

Answer (score 0):

Your `FUNCTIONTORUN()` blocks the UI thread.
Spread some `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()` inside your long-running functions to process events (so the UI updates).
This, as mentioned, will update the UI and let the application respond to other events.
You might want to disable the button that triggers this long-running function, or other long-running functions.

Comment: Yeah I know, I would just like it to be running as the function is running.

Comment: So put some `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();` in your long-running function. It will update the UI! This will also prevent the application from becoming unresponsive!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to put FUNCTIONTORUN() into sepratae thread, and still it's execution call 
[ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx) method, in order to raise `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` where you can update your porgress bar value. I suppose, as I don't see it in the code provided, you *don't* call `ReportProgress` function somewhere in the code.

**EDITED**: saw `ReportProgress` function.

So move your function into separate thread and update the value of progress bar into the main thread.

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an additional background worker with a DoWork that contains the call to your FUNCTIONTORUN() inside of it and a RunWorkerCompleted that makes your bar stop or go invisible.  Then, instead of calling FUNCTIONTORUN(), call backGroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();

This should prevent the function from freezing your UI.  I ran into this issue last summer doing nearly the exact same thing, and fixed it using backgroundworkers.